# jQuery Isotope - Masonry container height is set to 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I've got the following problem. `Isotope` sets the height of my container always to `0px`.

I checked for floats and other usual problem sources. All seems to be fine.

My class for the to-be arragened elements looks like this:

```
div#image-area div {
    width: 6.25%;
    height: 6.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, took me ages to figure it out!

**Isotope does not support percentual image sizes.**

Just choose a static width like `100px` and everything's fine!